# Poissons Equation to calculate potentials

Tags: electric-fields, charge, potential, conductors

How can I use the poissons equation to determine the potential due to a charge placed near a conducting sphere. I think the boundary conditions are potential at r =a and the potential at infinity is 0. But I dont know how to include the charge and how to describe the charge density of a point particle.(maybe as a 3D dirac delta function), but I also dont know how to solve the equation.

Comment: Have you tried using method of images?

Comment: This is a textbook question. It is typically solved by introducing a mirror charge inside the sphere and one has to chose position and strength such the the field lines are perpendicular on the sphere's surface. Is it this what you want, or do you really need to write it in form of a differential equation?

Comment: The thing that I actually want to calculate is much more complicated. 2 parametric conducting surfaces ( most probably cylinders) placed at an angle 'Theta' from the x axis and a mirror of that at '-Theta' and at the origin is a charged body. I just wanted to go step by step understanding 1 part of the problem at a time. So, I want to solve the differential equation than the mirror charges method as the differential equation is applicable to my problem